# SQL оконные функции группировка по максимальному заданному количеству строку

Tags: sql

Дана таблица вида:

| date | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| 20220323 | 10 |
| 20220225 | 21 |
| 20220220 | 17 |
| 20220218 | 25 |
| 20220207 | 76 |
| 20220128 | 14 |
| 20220125 | 10 |

date - это дата записи
cnt - количество записей в таблице за эту дату.

Требуется сгруппировать таблицу так, чтобы за любой период количество записей не превышало 60. Если количество записей больше 60, то остается только одна эта дата.
Итоговая таблица должна получиться вида:

| date_to | date_from | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20220323 | 20220220 | 48 |
| 20220218 | 20220218 | 25 |
| 20220207 | 20220207 | 76 |
| 20220128 | 20220125 | 24 |

Явно просятся оконные функции, но как сгруппировать значения по максимальной сумме?

Comment: исходные приведтите в виде insert запроса, и укажите конкретную СУБД.

Comment: Оконные функции тут не помогут. Только рекурсивное CTE или итеративная (курсор) процедура.

Comment: insert into table
VALUES ('20220323','10');
VALUES ('20220225','21');
VALUES ('20220220','17');
VALUES ('20220218','25');
VALUES ('20220207','76');
VALUES ('20220128','14');
VALUES ('20220125','10');

СУБД Oracle

Comment: @Akina, спасибо, будем разбираться. Если есть возможность как-то упростить, был бы признателен.

Comment: Еще тестил с оконной NTILE(). Но там проблема в том, что он разбивает на группы с одинаковым количеством записей.

Comment: Не парься - у тебя база плавает в зависимости от суммы для предыдущей записи, а потому статическое деление не стреляет вообще никак.

Answer (score 1):

Пример реализации для MySQL 8+.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM ( SELECT `date`, 
                  cnt, 
                  cnt `count`, 
                  1 grp_no
           FROM test
           ORDER BY `date` LIMIT 1 ) first_row
    UNION ALL
    SELECT next_row.`date`, 
           next_row.cnt,
           CASE WHEN next_row.cnt + cte.`count` > 60
                THEN next_row.cnt
                ELSE next_row.cnt + cte.`count`
                END,
           cte.grp_no + (next_row.cnt + cte.`count` > 60)
    FROM cte
    JOIN LATERAL ( SELECT *
                   FROM test
                   WHERE test.`date` > cte.`date`
                   ORDER BY test.`date` LIMIT 1 ) next_row
)
SELECT MAX(`date`) date_to,
       MIN(`date`) date_from,
       MAX(`count`) `count`
FROM cte
GROUP BY grp_no;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1ff82c94d115512d10f23ca0a8ed7df8